# Anode for buried galvanized steel tube

Tags: corrosion, anode

I recently installed an trampoline in my garden. The inclination made it necessary to bury parts of the trampolines feet in the earth.

Since matching replacement feet are hard to source I am interested to protect the feet from corrosion. I wonder if sacrificial anodes are a viable way to protect the metal? Do I need an anode for each foot?

The trampoline feet are made of several individual (hot dip)? galvanized steel tubes stuck together and fixed each with a bolt. The coating is old and partly worn. At several places the joints are also covered by earth. The entire assembly looks like this:

[image]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trampoline_with_enclosure.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The industrial way is both coating and cathodic protection ( sacrificial anodes/aluminum).The coating greatly reduces the amperage needed from the anodes. In your case it would be so easy and cheap to drive several inch lengths of aluminum angle into the ground that I would put in several ( each one attached with a wire to the steel frame). For a limited life item ,I would not bother with coating although that is best practice. In industry they would measure soil resistivity to decide how many anodes ,but,again, not necessary for your case. The aluminum could also be used to anchor the trampoline to the ground.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not too late, I feel that a properly applied heavy duty corrosion resistant coating would be a more effective (and simpler) solution than cathodic protection. The movement of the unit during use would likely interrupt continuity at the joints, making bonding jumpers necessary. Just seems like a difficult way to tackle this problem...